# Adding literals to json from PHP

Tags: php, string, json, literals

I'm using a PHP Controller to format an options array for jqPlot on the front end.

Essentially, it takes the data from the database via a model, and formats it into a way jqPlot can understand, then passes it to the view.

I have a bit of a conundrum whereby some fields are required to be literals rather than strings.

Example, from my controller:

```
$formatted['seriesDefaults'] = array(
    'renderer' => "$j.jqplot.BarRenderer",
     'rendererOptions' => array(
         'fillToZero' => true
     )
 );
```

This is then run through `json_encode` to get the JSON output.

The command `$j.jqplot.BarRenderer` is a jQuery instruction which needs to be rendered on the front end without quotes.

The JSON is rendered like this:

```
{
    "seriesDefaults":{
        "renderer":"$j.jqplot.BarRenderer",
        "rendererOptions"
            ...
    }
}
```

Ideally, to be interpreted correctly by jQuery in the view, it needs to be like this:

```
{
    "seriesDefaults":{
        "renderer": $j.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        "rendererOptions"
            ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way I could achieve this without adjusting my methodology?

Comment: Why would you want to generate invalid json. Jqplot has to offer a better method. This is not an javascript object were you can simply put in javascript at any point(You could hack your way around using eval.). Even the first posted json is invalid btw. (" vs. ')

Comment: The jqplot.BarRenderer is an object that allows a series of data to be interpreted as a Bar, not a Line graph. It's in the documentation: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/optionsTutorial-txt.html My aim isn't to write invalid JSON, it's instead to write valid jqPlot options; it's just unfortunate that those two things aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Rangad also, these are trivial examples, which I wrote specifically for the question. I see that they are invalid with regard to the quotes and I'll correct. I trust you can still see what I mean in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you're asking for is to not just *pass data* between two different systems (PHP and JS), but in fact to dynamically produce source code of one language (JS) in another. Yes, trying to pass one "literal" crosses over that line. And it's not a good idea IMO. Data is independent of its context, it can be evaluated as needed. Source code only works in a specific context (e.g. you *have* to include the jqplot library before this code, or it will break). Wanting to produce and pass source code instead of data makes your code less flexible and more brittle. Not to mention that it just makes it more difficult to produce, since `json_encode` explicitly does not allow anything but pure data.

I'd suggest simply post-processing your data in JavaScript a bit:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode(['renderer' => 'bar', ...]); ?>;

var renderers = {
    bar : $j.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    ...
};

data.renderer = renderers[data.renderer];
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I am trying to write a post processing function in JS now and hopefully that'll resolve it.

Comment: Post processing was the way forward and your solution was great.